# Why does my main program default to the except?

Tags: python

Could you possibly check my syntax and tell me why the debugger skips my `try` statement and skips to the `except`.

`book` class:

```
class book(object):
    
    def _init_(self, title, author, numPages):
        if title is None:
            raise ValueError("invalid 'title' argument. please try again")
        if author is None:
            raise ValueError("invalid 'author' argument. please try again")
        if numPages <= 0:
            raise ValueError("invalid 'numPages' argument. please try again")
        
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.numPages = numPages
```

`main` class:

```
from book import book

def printBook (b):
    if b is None:
        raise ValueError('invalid book argument')
    print (b.author + ": " + b.title + "\n" +" Number of page: " + b.numPages )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try: 
        b1 = book("The Eye of the World", "Robert Jordan", 685)
        b2 = book("The Heir of Novron", "Michael J. Sullivan", 932)
        
        printBook(b1)
        printBook(b2)
        
    except:
        print("ERROR: INVALID BOOK")
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting?. normally I am not so strict,  but (as you may know), indentation is important in python..

Comment: Please review your indentation. Also `'_init_' != '__init__'`.

Comment: Also Output your exception message to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Don't use blanket `except` clauses. If you hadn't used a blanket `except`, you would have gotten a useful error message to help you debug this (and which would not have been a ValueError).

Comment: @PeterParker I now understand what you mean. This was for a school assignment and our class was given zero information about the basics of Python prior to this assignment's distribution. We were sort of expected to go in and do it by only looking at similar examples, where the importance of indentation isn't nearly as evident to the untrained total beginner.

Comment: @user2357112 I understand that is bad practice, but due to the simplicity of the specifications for this program, I didn't see it totally necessary to cover each and every possible exception separately.

Comment: @JustinMoon: For a finished project you can catch the exception like you did, but user2357112 is right, that debugging of your code is much simpler if you see the error message ;-). Also you can react more flexible and give your user better information what went wrong: Your own mishap is a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 2 mistakes:

1. Constructor is called `__init__` as jonsharpe already mentioned
2. you need `str()` for  concatenation of ints and string. So you need to modify your print function:

   ```
   print (b.author + ": " + b.title + "\n" +" Number of page: " + str(b.numPages) )
   ```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I'm using an IDE that automatically inputted the `__init__` constructor as `_init_`. Like I said, I am a total beginner to Python. These lines of code are literally the first I've ever written.